# Get the search element only on 404

Tags: search, sidebar, 404-error

I know `get_sidebar( );` is used to get the widget sidebar , but how do I request one element from it?

For instance, if I want to show the search or most read only? I know there is a way to specify the sidebar for page like `get_sidebar('404' );`  for example

How do I do this? I've created the `404.php` page. Do I have to register other sidebar or  do I have to create "404_sidebar.php"?

So, how do I get the "search" element only when my website return error 404?

Comment: @Pieter Goosen thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include the search form in your `404.php` file using the [`get_search_form()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_search_form) function.

Using `get_sidebar( '404' );` would look for a file called `sidebar-404.php` and fall back on `sidebar.php` if needed. [`get_sidebar()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_sidebar)

Comment: شــــكراً.... thanx .... it work

Comment: عفواً (did I do that right?)

Comment: actually i don't know this 'get_search_form()' i put it in the '404.php' and style it again.....
yes you did ... i think you are Arabic lol